# Display recent posts with thumbnail within Masonry

Tags: recent-posts, masonry

On a page-template, I need to display recent 10 posts. So I tried to use, `wp_get_recent_posts`, [found here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_recent_posts) in the codex, which I think is an appropriate hook for the purpose.The rest of the code is from my archive.php which displays the post-thumbnails in [masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) just fine. I simply would like to achieve the same thing with the recent posts. This is what my code looks like :

```
<?php 
/* 
Template Name: Recent Profiles 
*/          
get_header(); 
?>

<h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>    

<div id="content">
<div id="masonry">


<?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

<div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item --> 
<div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><!--BEGIN .hentry -->





<?php
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => '10' );
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
    if ( has_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"])) {    
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]). '">';
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"], 'archive_grid');
        echo '</a>';
    }
}
?>





</div><!--END .hentry-->  
</div><!--END .item -->

<?php endwhile; endif; ?>

<?php get_template_part('includes/index-loadmore'); ?>

</div><!--END #masonry -->
<div id="masonry-new"></div>

<!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
        <div class="post-navigation clearfix">
            <?php dt_pagination(); ?>
        <!--END .post-navigation -->
        </div>

    </div><!-- #content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Issue : The issue is, the code is just displaying one recent post thumbnail instead of the expected 10. Please help me out for what I might be missing here. Perhaps something wrong with the loop. FYI `archive_grid` is the name of the custom thumbnail.

Comment: Seems like you don't have enough featured images in the latest 10 number of posts.

Comment: @Subharanjan I have my setting as setting->reading->Blog pages show at most->20 posts

Comment: Have you tried dumping `$recent_posts`? How many posts do you actually get from function return?

Answer (score 1):

Add the meta_key parameter to fetch the latest posts which have featured image set. `$args = array( 'numberposts' => '10', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' );`

```
<?php
/* 
Template Name: Recent Profiles 
*/
get_header();
?>
<h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

    <div id="content">
        <div id="masonry">
            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="item normal" data-order='1'><!--BEGIN .item -->
                    <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="featured-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><!--BEGIN .hentry -->
                        <?php
                        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '10', 'meta_key' => '_thumbnail_id' );
                        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
                        foreach ( $recent_posts as $recent ) {
                            if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"] ) ) {
                                echo '<a href="' . get_permalink( $recent["ID"] ) . '">';
                                echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"], 'archive_grid' );
                                echo '</a>';
                            }
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <!--END .hentry-->
                </div><!--END .item -->
            <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
            <?php get_template_part( 'includes/index-loadmore' ); ?>
        </div>
        <!--END #masonry -->
        <div id="masonry-new"></div>
        <!--BEGIN .post-navigation -->
        <div class="post-navigation clearfix">
            <?php dt_pagination(); ?>
            <!--END .post-navigation -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- #content -->
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: @subhranjan thanks for trying, but that did no work.

Answer (score -3):

You're trying to display in a custom template, so use query post type.

Check this [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/display-the-most-recent-post-in-each-category--cms-22677).

Comment: please, link only answers are bad because the content is going to disapear at some point leaving the answer useless, and because it is hard to know from the answer if visiting the link is actually worth your time